# Show install logs when installing through command line on Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am building a .bat installer to install several tools such as Java JDK and Git. I've managed to configure it to install these tools in silent mode but I wanted to get any kind of installation logs being displayed when the .exe is being executed (and therefore installing the software).

Currently, I am doing it this way (example for Java JDK):

```
@echo off

echo ****************
echo Java
echo ****************
echo ** Checking if Java JDK is already installed **
java -version | findstr /r /c:"java version" && ( echo ** Java JDK already installed ** ) || (
    echo ------ Proceed to install Java JDK 1.8.0_181
    echo ------ Installing
    "%~dp0\jdk-8u181x64.exe" /s
    echo ------ Verifying installation
    java -version | findstr /r /c:"java version"  && ( echo ** Java JDK installed with success ** ) || ( echo ** Something went wrong ** )
)
```

When the JDK is being installed, the console keeps displaying `------ Installing` but I wanted some king of logs from the installation to be dispalyed to let the user know that something is happening.

Is there a way to do it?

Best regards!

Comment: So, you're installing silently, but wanting the silent installation not to be silent! _BTW, it would be wiser to use, `java -version 2>Nul |`, the `/R` option for your `FindStr` command is not necessary, and `%~dp0` already has a trailing backslash, so following it with another is also unnecessary._

Comment: You will need to wait until after Java is installed, then TYPE the log filename. I do not know what or if the Java install creates a text log file.

Comment: @Compo I am aware of what you're saying but do you know any way to let java post the log messages while being installed? 
When I chose the silent mode I was hoping it would install without requesting any user interaction (press "Next", "Finish" whatever) but I wanted the user to know that something's happening in the background.

Comment: If it is showing **Installing** in the console window, doesn't that mean something is happening.  Seems logical to me.  I try to follow the **K.I.S.S** method when writing code.

Comment: I guess I'll acccept your answer, @Compo. Cheers!